# TFS Build Definition Issue

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild

I am trying to create a build definition using TFS 2012.
I have set up the drop folder as local machine folder.
It creates drop folder and copy the dlls only when I do a get latest in TFS.
Can anyone please suggst how to copy the components to a drop folder in local machine automatically?(without doing get latest)

Answer (score 0):

If the "Copy build output to the following drop folder (UNC path, such \server\share)" is selected in the build definition, when queue a new build, build output files (.exe, .dll) and some log files are copied to the UNC folder. That is, the files are not copied during the Get Latest process.